# Kendo ASP.NET MVC Grid and WebAPI - Data does not show up in grid

Tags: asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, response, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an APIController with a HttpGet which returns this JSON response:

```
[{"Customer":"AAAA","Office":"Off1"},{"Customer":"AAAA","Office":"Off2"}]
```

This is hosted on a remote server.

I'm testing my local client, connecting to this server with this:

```
<div class="k-content">
    <div id="Grid"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "http://<remoteserver>/<apicontroller>/<actionMethod>",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { customerFilter: "AAAA", topFilter: "10" }
        }
    },
   schema: {
        model: {
            Customer: "Customer",
            Office: "Office"
        }
   }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            height: 400,
            columns: [
                { field: "Customer" },
                { field: "Office" }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Checking in fiddler, I get the response shown above. However, the grid is empty. 
If i hard code the data into the data source like below, the grid populates, so it seems as if, even though the response is received, the grid doesn't know how to parse it.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data:
          [{"Customer":"AAAA","Office":"Off1"},{"Customer":"AAAA","Office":"Off2"}],
        schema: {
            model: {
                Customer: "Customer",
                Office: "Office"
            }
        }
```

Anyone have some ideas what might be the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration of the datasource is incorrect. The Kendo UI documentation can be hard to follow, but this is how you need to define a datasource:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: "http://<remoteserver>/<apicontroller>/<actionMethod>",
      dataType: "json",
      data: { customerFilter: "AAAA", topFilter: "10" }
    }
  },
  schema: {
    model: {
      fields: {
        Customer: {},
        Office: {}
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: no need to mention entire url. You can just specify uri. example:var uri = 'api/products';
      
      var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
          transport: {
              read: {
                  url:uri,
                  dataType: "json"
              }
              },

Answer (score 0):

No need to mention entire url. You can also just specify uri.

example:

```
    var uri = 'api/products';      
  var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      transport: {
          read: {
              url:uri,
              dataType: "json"
          }
          }
   });
```